# How to know which alternative rule ANTLR parser is currently in during visit

Tags: java, antlr4, visitor-pattern

If we look at the bash sources, and the yacc grammar specifically, we can see that all redirections are defined as such :

```
redirection
        :   GREATER WORD
        |   LESS WORD
        |   NUMBER GREATER WORD
        |   NUMBER LESS WORD
        |   REDIR_WORD GREATER WORD
        |   REDIR_WORD LESS WORD
        |   GREATER_GREATER WORD
        |   NUMBER GREATER_GREATER WORD
        |   REDIR_WORD GREATER_GREATER WORD
        |   GREATER_BAR WORD
        |   NUMBER GREATER_BAR WORD
        |   REDIR_WORD GREATER_BAR WORD
        |   LESS_GREATER WORD
        |   NUMBER LESS_GREATER WORD
        |   REDIR_WORD LESS_GREATER WORD
        |   LESS_LESS WORD
        |   NUMBER LESS_LESS WORD
        |   REDIR_WORD LESS_LESS WORD
        |   LESS_LESS_MINUS WORD
        |   NUMBER LESS_LESS_MINUS WORD
        |   REDIR_WORD  LESS_LESS_MINUS WORD
        |   LESS_LESS_LESS WORD
        |   NUMBER LESS_LESS_LESS WORD
        |   REDIR_WORD LESS_LESS_LESS WORD
        |   LESS_AND NUMBER
        |   NUMBER LESS_AND NUMBER
        |   REDIR_WORD LESS_AND NUMBER
        |   GREATER_AND NUMBER
        |   NUMBER GREATER_AND NUMBER
        |   REDIR_WORD GREATER_AND NUMBER
        |   LESS_AND WORD
        |   NUMBER LESS_AND WORD
        |   REDIR_WORD LESS_AND WORD
        |   GREATER_AND WORD
        |   NUMBER GREATER_AND WORD
        |   REDIR_WORD GREATER_AND WORD
        |   GREATER_AND DASH
        |   NUMBER GREATER_AND DASH
        |   REDIR_WORD GREATER_AND DASH
        |   LESS_AND DASH
        |   NUMBER LESS_AND DASH
        |   REDIR_WORD LESS_AND DASH
        |   AND_GREATER WORD
        |   AND_GREATER_GREATER WORD
        ;
```

In my visitor, when `visitRedirection` is called this feels almost impossible to know which alternative the visitor is currently in easily.. I could label each alternatives using `#` and labels but adding 43 visit methods for just a single production rules seems somewhat excessive.

Usually I would just do some `null` checks by doing `ctx.GREATER() != null` to know if the first alternative was chosen, but in this example there's almost always 2 clashing alternatives, for instance :

```
GREATER WORD
NUMBER GREATER WORD
```

So should I do `ctx.NUMBER() != null && ctx.GREATER() != null` to match the second alternative and `ctx.NUMBER() == null && ctx.GREATER() != null` to match the first ?

Is there an easier or cleaner way to be able to know which specific alternative the visitor is currently in ?

Comment: The way I would do this is to [get the first child of the node](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/), then test the token type. Alternately, you could label each alt.

Comment: 43 labels is a bit much, and i'm trying to find a cleaner way. I saw `RuleContext::getChild` that can let me get the first child, but that returns a `ParseTree` and i can't see how to get the token type from the javadoc. Something that did catch my eye was `getAltNumber`; it seems like exactly what i would want but it says it's not set by default so i'm not sure how to enable that either

Comment: Cast 1st child to TerminalNode, then getSymbol(), getType(), and test.

Comment: Nice that does work, i guess i just have to branch a lot (due to how many alternatives this production rule has) but that does help a bit more than just labeling everything, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restructure your grammar to have less alternatives. Many of them have common leading or trailing parts, for example:

```
redirection
        :   GREATER WORD
        |   LESS WORD
        |   NUMBER (GREATER | LESS) WORD
        |   REDIR_WORD (GREATER | LESS | LESS_LESS_MINUS) WORD
        |   ...
```

This way you have a unique first token in each alt, which you can then assign to a local variable:

```
redirection
        :   op = GREATER WORD
        |   op = LESS WORD
        |   op = NUMBER subOp= (GREATER | LESS) WORD
        |   op = REDIR_WORD subOp =(GREATER | LESS | LESS_LESS_MINUS) WORD
        |   ...
```

With that you can easily check in which alt you are in your listener/visitor:

```
public exitRedirection(RedirectionContext ctx) {
    switch (ctx.op.getType()) {
        case YourParser.GREATER_WORD: {
            break;
        }

        case YourParser.REDIR_WORD: {
            switch (ctx.supOp.getType()) {
                case YourParser.LESS_LESS_MINUS: {
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I simply copy pasted the production rule from bash's `parser.y` yacc file, but your method is quite nice, thanks i'll do just that!

Comment: I managed to shrink it to simply 3 alternatives, that's a really nice way of doing things, here's the new production rule : https://pastebin.com/Q8Wm8aBQ
Thanks again!

Comment: And this way it's faster too! See this [blog post from Gabriele Tomassetti](https://tomassetti.me/improving-the-performance-of-an-antlr-parser/), in the section "Consolidating sub rules".

Comment: Oh so basically as long as i have *single* tokens as alternatives in parenthesis, it uses a lookup table (e.g. a set) to match the right token without branching if I understood correctly. I'm definitely saving this article to refer to, thanks!

Comment: Is there no actual way to determine which alternative rule was parsed without changing the grammar?

Comment: @pizzapants184 I have the same question.
For example:

```
oC_ListOperatorExpression
                      :  ( SP IN SP? oC_PropertyOrLabelsExpression )
                          | ( SP? '[' oC_Expression ']' )
                          | ( SP? '[' oC_Expression? '..' oC_Expression? ']' )
                          ;

```
How can I tell which alternative I am using in:

```
  antlrcpp::Any visitOC_ListOperatorExpression(
      CypherParser::OC_ListOperatorExpressionContext* ctx) override {}
```

Comment: @cpchung Don't hijack other questions. Ask your own one where the community can ask detail questions and so on.

Comment: @MikeLischke thanks, asked it here instead:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71399851/how-to-know-which-alternative-rule-antlr-parser-is-currently-in-during-visit-wit