# Is there a way to know which alternative rule ANTLR parser is currently in?

Tags: antlr

I want to know which alternative rule antlr is current in .I read "the definitivie antlr4 reference",it use ctx.getChildCount() or ctx.ID()!=null to know which alternative rule antlr is currently in.

But I want to know is there a method which could give the specific index of the alternative rule.

I see this question [How to know which alternative rule ANTLR parser is currently in during visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148460/how-to-know-which-alternative-rule-antlr-parser-is-currently-in-during-visit) ,but it doesn't have the answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use [alt labels](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) to know in which alternative you are, or try to use  `options {contextSuperClass=org.antlr.v4.runtime.RuleContextWithAltNum;}` ([link](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/RuleContextWithAltNum.html)), but that is probably not what you want. The `contextSuperClass` will only tell you in the child rule what the index in its parent is:

```
parent
 : child_a
 | child_b
 | child_c
 | child_d
 | child_e
 ;

child_d
 : ... // in a listener, you can now get index 3 from the parent context
 ;
```

so you cannot do:

```
parent
 : child_a
 | child_b
 | child_c
 | child_d // get index 3 here
 | child_e
 ;
```

Note that the `contextSuperClass` is only available in Java it seems by looking at the remark in the link: "I'm only putting into Java runtime as I'm certain I'm the only one that will really every use this."