# How does lab.antlr.org get the parser rule and alternative number?

Tags: antlr4

I have been playing with [ANTLR Lab](http://lab.antlr.org) *(really nice by the way)* and was wondering how it is able to label the matching parser rule and alternative number. For example, below `content:1`, `x_tag:2` and `x_tag:3` are all rule names and the number after the colon is the alternative within that rule.

[image]

I have built a recognizer from my grammar but cannot see from looking at the runtime API how to access them from within a custom listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, ANTLR Lab and the [ANTLR IntelliJ plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7358-antlr-v4) both use the [RuleContextWithAltNum](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/RuleContextWithAltNum.html) to set and get the alternative.

Note that it is only implemented in Java. From the documentation:

> A handy class for use with options {contextSuperClass=org.antlr.v4.runtime.RuleContextWithAltNum;} that provides a backing field / impl for the outer alternative number matched for an internal parse tree node. I'm only putting into Java runtime as I'm certain I'm the only one that will really every use this.

Also see the related stackoverflow Q&A: [Is there a way to know which alternative rule ANTLR parser is currently in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70360275/is-there-a-way-to-know-which-alternative-rule-antlr-parser-is-currently-in)

Comment: Bart, Very insightful of you to mention that `RuleContextWithAltNum` only being available in Java. My target is C# so I resorted to Alternative Labels.