# How to know which alternative rule ANTLR parser is currently in during visit without changing the grammar

Tags: antlr4

I looked at these and they don't seem to solve the problem:

[Is there a way to know which alternative rule ANTLR parser is currently in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70360275/is-there-a-way-to-know-which-alternative-rule-antlr-parser-is-currently-in)

[How to know which alternative rule ANTLR parser is currently in during visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148460/how-to-know-which-alternative-rule-antlr-parser-is-currently-in-during-visit)

For example:

```
oC_ListOperatorExpression : 
( SP IN SP? oC_PropertyOrLabelsExpression ) 
| ( SP? '[' oC_Expression ']' ) 
| ( SP? '[' oC_Expression? '..' oC_Expression? ']' ) ;
```

In this particular case, alternative 2 and alternative 3 have no special tokens or tokens in a fixed position I can leverage to differentiate them.

How can I tell which alternative am I using in the following without changing the grammar?

```
antlrcpp::Any visitOC_ListOperatorExpression( 
 CypherParser::OC_ListOperatorExpressionContext* ctx) override {
}
```

I am using the c++ runtime of ANTLR4 4.9.3.1.

The full grammar:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/M18/Cypher.g4

Comment: You don't need labels. You know you are working on the 1st alt if `context.IN() != null`. To distinguish between 2nd and 3rd alts, test the children of context for a token with a token equal to "..". There will be at max 6 children, so I seriously doubt that this will require gobs of computational time. Unfortunately, the grammar is poorly defined for token symbols. There should be a lexer rule for ".." rather than only a string literal in the parser rule. As there is none, you will need to precompute what that token type (int) would be, or just compare the text of the token to "..".

Comment: I think this is an acceptable solution for this particular case. I was looking for a general solution using ttype or similar.

Comment: Actually, there is another way. You could add a class `MyContext` that is derived from ParserRuleContext, set the options in the grammar `options { contextSuperClass=MyContext; }`. The purpose of `MyContext` is to record what alt was used in the parse, which is set in the generated parser. In `MyContext`, you would need to override `setAltNumber(int altNumber)` and `getAltNumber()`, which would operate against a backing field `int _alt`. You could then use `getAltNumber()` in your visitor or listener. Note, the names of types and methods for the C++ runtime may be different.

Comment: Unfortunately, this would require a grammar change. Oh well....

Comment: It turns out you can use "-DcontextSuperClass=MyContext" when generating the parser from the Antlr tool jar. The grammar does not then have to be changed, and you can then get the alt used for the parse.

Comment: `-DcontextSuperClass=MyContext` do I only need to add this option when generating the parser? If not, any toy example or document for this?

Comment: You only need the option when generating the parser. I have an example, which I used to check if this would work--it does. But, it is in C#. You will need to fiddle with cmake or your build files for C++.

Answer (score 1):

You could add labels to the two `oC_Expression`s in the last alternative.  Then you could check for the presence/absence of those.

(Or even just check for the 2nd `oC_Expression`